# Checking divisibility by large numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am currently familiar with the method of checking if a number is divisible by $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $8$, $9$, $10$, $11$. However is there a way to check if a no is divisible by $23$ ?

I read something [at this link](http://amca01.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/divisibility-tests-and-liljevalchs-theorem/) regarding this matter but couldn't really figure out what the author was trying to say. Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is [a repeat](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/148784/742); see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/52778/742). See in particular [Bill Dubuque's answer to the latter](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/52815/742)

Comment: Looking closer, I don't think this is a duplicate, since it's referencing the *reversed* universal test, which hasn't been (explicitly) explained in the prior links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind "all those checkings" is to look at divisibility by computing the number you want to check divisibility modulo the divisor. For instance, the trick for computing divisibility by $11$ all reduces to 
$$
a \times 10^3 + b \times 10^2 + c \times 10 + d \equiv -a + b - c + d \pmod{11}
$$
so that you can look at the alternated sum of the numbers instead of looking at the big one. You can develop a similar trick modulo $23$, for instance since $100 \equiv 8 \pmod {23}$, you have 
$$
a \times 100^2 + b \times 100 + c \equiv a \times 64 + b \times 8 + c \equiv a \times (-5) + b \times 8 + c \pmod {23}.
$$
Perhaps the trick doesn't look quite as good, but that's because the tricks work well when the numbers are small or pretty (such as : it is easy to look at divisibility by $10000000000$).

Hope that helps,

Comment: @Mark : Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 6):

Here is the explanation to that link:

We know that $10 \cdot 7 = 70 \equiv 1 \mod 23$ as $3 \cdot 23 = 69$.

Thus, if we consider $10a + b \mod 23$ and we note that $7$ is coprime to $23$, then $10a + b \equiv 0 \mod 23 \iff 7(10a + b) = 70a + 7b \equiv a + 7b \equiv 0 \mod 23$

And that is how he got that $10a + b$ is divisible by $23$ iff $a + 7b$ is divisible by $23$. And this lets that blogger get rid of a digit, more or less, at each step to easily verify divisibility.

Comment: +1 This explanation tacitly uses the fact that $7$ and $10$ are inverses modulo $23$. I bring it up because that leads to a way to generalize divisibility tests of this kind for different moduli.

Answer (score 3):

He shows that any integer of the form $10a + b$ is divisible by 23 if and only if $a + 7b$ is divisible by 23.  So for a number $n$ with more than one digit, you can repeatedly replace it with the number $a + 7b$, where $b$ is the last digit of $n$, and $a$ is the rest.

In his example, we have $n = 146096$ and we can write it as $10 \cdot 14609 + 6$, i.e. $a = 14609$, $b = 6$, and therefore $n$ is divisible by 23 if and only if $7a + b = 7 \cdot 14609 + 6 = 14651$ is.  And we just repeat this until we have a small enough number.

As you can see, this is not a very practical test because we still have to do those multiplications.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\begin{eqnarray}\mod\ 23\!:\ \ 0&\equiv&\rm\, \ \  a\,10^3 + b\,10^2 + c\,10 + d \\
\iff\ 0 &\equiv&\rm\,(a\,10^3 + b\,10^2 + c\,10 + d)\,7^3 \\
\iff\ 0 &\equiv&\rm\ \ a\ \ \ \, +\, \, \ \  b\:7\ \,  +\, \  c\:7^2 + d\ 7^3\quad by\quad 10\cdot 7\equiv 1\,\ (mod\ 23)
\end{eqnarray}$

Now evaluate it mod $23\,$ as $\rm\ a + 7\,(b + 7\,(c + 7\,d))\ $ in *Horner form* as [I explain in detail here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89668/242) This is essentially the universal divisibility test applied to the *reversed* radix polynomial. It has the disadvantage that, while it correctly tests zero equivalence, it does not yield the actual remainder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that doesn't need modular arithmetic or lots of multiplication you could do this:

1) Subtract a multiple of your number (since pn-pk=p(n-k))

2) Divide by a different co-prime number (by fundamental theorem of arithmetic)

Since neither of these affect divisibility you can do them as much as you like in any order until you reach numbers you know are (or aren't) divisible.

It takes a bit longer but using these we can see if something is a divisor and it can even be done in your head.

For example:
Does 75233 divide by 23?

75233 - 23 = 75210

75210 / 10 = 7521

7521 - 6900 = 621

621 / 3 = 207

207 - 23 = 184

184 / 2 = 92

92 / 4 = 23

So 75233 is divisible by 23

This will work for any divisor.